# how to upload image in iOS and Android emulators in sauce labs virtual machine through appium webdriver using python language

Tags: android, python, ios, appium, saucelabs

Here, I am trying to upload an image to the sauce labs virtual machine(iOS and Android).

I tried with `element.send_keys(path of local machine image) ,but the image was not uploaded.

`photo_url=str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))))`

`photo_url = os.path.join(photo_url, "car.png")`

---

```
def enter_fileUploadCntl_with(self, photo_url, wait):
    self._wait_and_complete_type(self._fileUploadCntl, photo_url, wait)
```

---

```
def _wait_and_complete_type(self, locator, input_text, wait_before_type):
    time.sleep(wait_before_type)
    self._type(locator, input_text)
```

---

```
def _type(self, locator, input_text):
   self._find(locator).send_keys(input_text)
```

---

```
def _find(self, locator):
    return self.driver.find_element(locator['by'], locator['value'])
```

Can any one please tell me another way to upload image running test case in sauce labs appium web driver through python?

Comment: We use `Multipart` format to upload images from `android` and `iOS`

Comment: Thank you, for answered. But, I want to upload image in virtual emulator on web during running test case. Is their any solution?